# Is there a more ruby-esque way to do this?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby since yesterday evening.

Here's a method I made that's supposed to print out multiples of any numbers up to any quantity.

```
def DisplayMultiples(multiplesOf, count)
  i = multiplesOf
  while i <= count
    if i % multiplesOf == 0
      puts i
    end
    i += 1
  end
end
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the code to something more fitting to the Ruby style? I'm coming from a C# background so I'd like to switch things up a bit.

**Edit:**

Where can I find documentation for methods/classes? For example, the first answer I received use the .times method (is it a method?). I can't find the documentation for that because I don't know what type it is, since Ruby doesn't have types.

Any suggestions?

Comment: One thing I'd suggest is to use underscores in your method/variable names, instead of camelCase. `def display_multiples(multiples_of, count)`

Comment: Documentation for Ruby comes bundled with it. Try typing `ri` at the command-line to get a list of all classes and modules it knows about. Try `ri Array` or `ri Time.now`. Also, `gem server` will start a tiny webserver on your machine so you can to go `http://localhost:8808` to get docs of any gems you have installed. Otherwise http://rubydoc.info is a good source.

Comment: i think the assumption is that 'count' is an integer type.   '.times()' is a method of the class integer.  check http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/ for the core classes and methods.

Comment: While loops are rarely used in Ruby. Blocks are de rigueur.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do:

```
def display_multiples(multiplesOf, count)
  count.times {|x| puts x * multiplesOf }
end
```

Comment: Just wanted to comment, my code prints `count` multiples, including zero, yours prints multiples up to a certain count. I thought mine made more sense from the method signature, but replicating your behavior exactly would be one extra step.

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing? What is the |x| supposed to do? As elaborate as possible please. Thank you.

Comment: And this is why Ruby is badass.

Comment: From "Ruby in 20 minutes": "A block is like an anonymous function or lambda. The variable between pipe characters is the parameter for this block." http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/

Comment: @yan, This method doesn't seem to replicate the results of the OPs. Using the input of multiplesOf = 10, and count = 100, I get results 10, 20, 30, ... , 970, 980, 990 instead of 10, 20, 30, ..., 100

Comment: @Matt Spinelli, I've commented on that above.

Comment: @Sergio, lookup Enumerable objects, blocks, and yield. From Matsumoto's The Ruby Programming Language (p 130) "... blocks may be parameterized. Vertical bars at the start of a block are like parentheses in a method definition - they hold a list of parameter names. The yield statement is like a method invocation; it is followed by zero or more expressions whose values are assigned to the block parameters."

Comment: @Steve: Thanks Steve, that was crystal clear. Ruby seems very succinct. :)

Comment: @yan. Sorry about that. I overlooked your comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
def display_multiples(number, limit)
  0.step(limit, number){|n| puts n}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def display_multiples(multiplesOf, count)
  (count/multiplesOf).times {|x| puts (x+1) * multiplesOf }
end
```

As for documentation, see [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org) and [gotapi.com](http://gotapi.com).

Answer (score 0):

```
def display_multiples(of,nb)
  p (of..of*nb).step(of).to_a
end

display_multiples(3,5) #display [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```